# Why pg_dump was not getting the password in cron job?

Tags: postgresql, cron, backup

We are using cron job to backup Postgres database on Ubuntu 12.04. The `pg_dump` command was added to a bash script which has been running for backing up SQLite. The command is:

```
pg_dump -U postgres -Fc mydbname > /home/myback_$now   #$now append last 2 digits of date to file name
```

A .pgpass file was created in the same home dir as it is for the bash script:

```
localhost:5432:mydbname:postgres:mypassword
```

Also did `chmod 600 .pgpass`.

The problem is that there are backup files generated but the size of them are all 0. In backup log, there is an error:

```
pg_dump: [archiver (db)] connection to database "mydbname" failed: fe_sendauth: no password supplied
```

It seems that the password in .pgpass was not referred correctly by `pg_dump`. What could be missing here in the backup config?

Comment: `cron` runs commands as a different user, unless you used your user crontab via `crontab -e`. How exactly did you create the cron job and where? Where exactly did you create the pgpass file?

Comment: .pgpass is in home dir. We use sudo crontab -e to create cron job. The job has worked for sqlite3. The job for postgres was added after sqlite3 jobs in the same bash file.

Comment: **WHICH** Home dir? Exact path. And show the full crontab line.

Comment: The home subdir for root.

Comment: `/root/.pgpass` ? Is that the *exact path*? And **show the full crontab line**.

Comment: Updated the post about the pg_dump and .pgpass.

Comment: I give up. You won't show the actual details and without unedited complete and accurate information I cannot help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If, as you stated in the comments, you did

```
sudo crontab -e
```

then you are editing the crontab of root, not the crontab of your own user.

Therefore the home directory that will be used will be root's home directory (normally /root, but I am not certain for Ubuntu).

Although you did not explicitly say so I am guessing you put the .pgpass file in the home directory of your user.

It is not necessary, or even a good idea, to run pg_backup as root, so I recommend putting your backup job in the crontab of your regular user.

Comment: Right. The home is the root home (it is /home/myroot. my root is the root user name). The .pgpass is in root's home. It is strange that it is not working.